# How to build a survey chatbot with streamlit_chat

Tags: streamlit

I am building a simple survey chatbot using streamlit. I have a list of questions {Q1, Q2, … Qn} that I want to ask a user and collect the user’s response in the database. For each user’s response to each question, I also have one follow-up question (FQ1 that I want to ask further and collect responses. The follow-up question is generated on the fly through a hugging face model.

In essence, here is the following workflow I want to be able to see in the chat history:

Bot: Q1
User Response: [text input]
Bot: FQ1 (follow-up question generated on the fly through a model)
User Response: [text input]

Bot: Q2
User Response: [text input]
Bot: FQ2 (follow-up question generated on the fly)
User Response: [text input]

...

Bot: Q5
User Response: [text input]
Bot: FQ5 (follow-up question generated on the fly)
User Response:

For now, if we assume the questions and follow-up questions are pre-defined lists, can someone please help provide a vanilla code to solve the above? There are multiple examples of streamlit chat components, but none of them deal with asking a pre-defined set of questions (something like a survey bot). Having a bunch of issues while playing through session variables.

Answer (score 0):

For hidden questions you can use an if block with streamlit:

```
import streamlit as st

st.title("Questionnaire with follow ups")

questions = {
  'Q1': "What is your first name?",
  'FQ1': "Oh cool, your first name is John! What's your last name?",
  "Q2": "Here's question 2...",
}

q1 = st.text_input(questions['Q1'])

if q1 == 'John':
  fq1 = st.text_input(questions['FQ1'])


q2 = st.text_input(questions['Q2'])
```

Here the follow up questions only appear on a condition with the first question. Hope this helps!